# Посчитать адрес для call инcтрукции

Tags: ассемблер, opcode

пытаюсь понять как вычислить адрес для вызова функции через call. Вот пример:

```
00000517 <_test_exit>:
 517:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
 51c:   c3                      ret    

0000051d <_start>:
 51d:   e8 f5 ff ff ff          call   517 <_test_exit>
 522:   e8 f0 ff ff ff          call   517 <_test_exit>
 527:   e8 eb ff ff ff          call   517 <_test_exit>
 52c:   e8 e6 ff ff ff          call   517 <_test_exit>
```

Вот возьмем первый call, вызывается адрес `0xfffff5`, но почему? Вот я сделал расчет - `0xfff517 + 5 - 0xfff51d`, результат -1, но почему в бинарнике стоит `0xfffff5`? Прошу помочь разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было по другому считать:

```
0xfff517 - (0xfff51d + 5)
```